# OpenCV Android - color issue using CameraBridgeViewBase

Tags: java, android, macos, opencv, android-emulator

I'm encountering a strange problem using Android emulators & OpenCV `CameraBridgeViewBase`.

Using `onCameraFrame` I get a picture that looks like it wasn't decoded properly.

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    return inputFrame.rgba();
}
```

Using 'inputFrame.gray()' I get what's expected - black and white image without artifacts or any other issues.

That's what I get:

[image: First picture]

[One more picture (a bigger one)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsTgz.png)

What I've tried so far:

1. Different API levels (from 15 up to 21).
2. Different emulators: Genymotion & Google Android emulator.
3. Different platform architectures - both ARM and Intel x86.
4. Launching emulator on different laptop with Linux: **it works** as expected, the issue is gone!
5. Launching apps, using OpenCV, downloaded from Play Store. They DO work! **However:**

   1. Launch app that works as expected, then close it.
   2. Launch your app (or one of the OpenCV tutorials), then close it.
   3. Launching app from the 5.1 again I see that it's affected by the same bug!
6. Different OpenCV versions (2.4.9 and 2.4.10).
7. Different versions of the OpenCV manager (one from the Play Store and 2.4.9 & 2.4.10 from OpenCV package).
8. Finally, as I noticed in 5.2, precompiled tutorial .apk files from the OpenCV package are affected by the issue too.

Everything works as expected on my real android devices.

After looking at sources of the `CameraBridgeViewBase` and Java/Native camera classes I came to the decision that the problem occurs while decoding image. Probably there is a problem with platform-specific camera output format (YUV, NV21). However, it's strange that .gray() gives out a proper image (without artifacts).

I'm using Mac OS X 10.10 Yosemite and MacBook Air with "Facetime HD" camera if that matters.

Any ideas on how to overcome this problem & help in finding the root of the problem are greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, after drilling into the problem I've found the root of the issue.

Let's take a look at the OpenCV `JavaCameraView` class and its `CameraBridgeViewBase` base class.
The problem was that camera frames received as `byte[]` array in `onPreviewFrame` method were decoded incorrectly.

The exact place of code where the decoding process takes place is an implementation of the `Mat rgba()` method in inner `JavaCameraFrame` class of the `JavaCameraView`:

```
    public Mat rgba() {
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mYuvFrameData, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21, 4);
        return mRgba;
    }
```

As we see, Imgproc.cvtColor(...) method is used in order to convert frame from YUV to RGBA. `NV21 YUV -> RGBA` conversion takes place there. During the initialization process we set the format to NV21, so this should be right. Moreover, [every Android device should support NV21](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ImageFormat.html#NV21). Also, we can check whether device accepted the format using debugger:

```
protected boolean initializeCamera(int width, int height) {
    ...
    params.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
    ...
    mCamera.setParameters(params);
    ...
    params = mCamera.getParameters();
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("Actual preview format is 0x%X", params.getPreviewFormat()));
}
```

Both phone (HTC Sensation) and emulator reported to be using NV21 indeed.

However, if we change `COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21` to `COLOR_YUV2RGB_I420` (YV12 and I420 is the same thing, just with Y and V inverted;) we'll see that emulator will get a proper color space finally.  Changing NV21 to YV12 in `params.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);` we'll get similar results. Looks like there's bug either in Imgproc.cvtColor, or in Android.

**Here comes the solution.**
Change `public Mat rgba()` the following way:

```
    public Mat rgba() {
        if (previewFormat == ImageFormat.NV21) {
            Imgproc.cvtColor(mYuvFrameData, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGBA_NV21, 4);
        }
        else if (previewFormat == ImageFormat.YV12) {
            Imgproc.cvtColor(mYuvFrameData, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV2RGB_I420, 4);  // COLOR_YUV2RGBA_YV12 produces inverted colors
        }
        return mRgba;
    }
```

`previewFormat` is a new `int` variable, it's declared this way:

```
private int previewFormat = ImageFormat.NV21;
```

Add following changes to the initialization:

```
protected boolean initializeCamera(int width, int height) {
        ...
                params.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
                // "generic" = android emulator
                if (Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("generic")) {
                    params.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.YV12);
                }
                ...
                mCamera.setParameters(params);
                params = mCamera.getParameters();
                previewFormat = params.getPreviewFormat();
        ...
}
```

**Important:**
Please note: this is just a temporary solution in order to make OpenCV usable with emulator in my case. Further research should be done. It's quite easy to check whether device uses correct image format in onPreviewFrame. I'll get back to this when I have some time.

Comment: Using Android Studio 1.5.1 and emulating API 23, the above only worked when `"generic"` was swapped to `"android"`. Works flawlessly after that change, though.

Comment: I just tried this and it works fine. Though, I am not sure whether this is the preferred approach or it should be fixed in a different manner. I have created an issue in the OpenCV repository, where if this is accepted it can be submitted as a pull request.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who use genymotion, the BRAND won't be call generic.
To solve this just simply change the code to

```
...
if (Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("generic") | Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("Android")) {
...
```

and it should works, or just printout the BRAND you are using and replace it on the "Android"

P.S The second condition will include the case that you are using genymotion which is also an emulator.

Cheers

Comment: Maybe I should explain further, the 2nd "or condition" will cover if you are using genymotion which is an emulator and commonly use by certain peoples.

Comment: Note that the condition should be || and not |

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed now in the code in git, as the Pull Request https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/8168 has been merged. It should be available in the next released version.