# camera preview from opencv shows bad/incorrect image. using javacameraview

Tags: opencv, android

The System I'm using is:
Mac + Eclipse + Opencv4Android (v3.0)

all samples and everything is running correctly except for the results or quality displayed by the camera. here is a sample below of how it looks
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tLiH0.jpg

This is not just through the emulator but also when I upload it to my phone.
in the image the tablet cover is actually bright red, the phone is blue. here is the clear image from the actual android camera app:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qv84u.jpg

the transparent layer on top is also a bother. I thought it was because of the alpha channel but I've tried removing it also why does it show up 4 times?

I've used only a basic code to setup my opencv here it is
AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="19" android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front.autofocus" android:required="false"/>
```

MainActivity:

```
private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
        case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: 
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");

            // Load native library after(!) OpenCV initialization
            // System.loadLibrary("mixed_sample");

            mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
            break;
        }
        default: {
            super.onManagerConnected(status);
        }
            break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mOpenCvCameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.aslgesturerecogapp_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    return inputFrame.rgba();
}
```

Here is my only layout file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:opencv="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.aslgesturerecogapp.MainActivity" >

<org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
    android:id="@+id/aslgesturerecogapp_surface_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    opencv:show_fps="true"
    opencv:camera_id="any"
    />
```

Comment: It seems the problem is wide spread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083097/opencv-android-color-issue-using-camerabridgeviewbase

Comment: unfortunately it is. [That](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083097/opencv-android-color-issue-using-camerabridgeviewbase) is the answer to this question

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have added opencv library to your project successfully.

Here is a sample code using OpenCV4android.

```
public class SampleCameraFrameAccessActivity extends Activity implements        CvCameraViewListener2, OnTouchListener{
private static final String  TAG = "SampleCameraFrameAccessActivity";

protected CameraBridgeViewBase cameraPreview;
protected Mat mRgba;

protected BaseLoaderCallback  mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
//                    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
//                    mOpenCvCameraView.setOnTouchListener(ColorRegionDetectionActivity.this);
                cameraPreview.enableView();
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.camera_sample_layout);

    cameraPreview = (CameraBridgeViewBase) findViewById(R.id.sample_test_camera_view);

    cameraPreview.setCvCameraViewListener(this);

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    if(cameraPreview != null){
        cameraPreview.disableView();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this, mLoaderCallback);
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mRgba =  new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mRgba.release();

}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

    return mRgba;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
```

}

And the XML Layout file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/sample_test_layout" >

    <org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/sample_test_camera_view" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can try this one.

Comment: Yes i loaded the OpenCV library correctly (opencv4android). My issue is not getting my project or even samples to run. They run fine, except for the camera quality as i showed in the first link. The camera shows a colorless image laced with a sort of translucent layer on top. The above sample also runs the same way. No change. Could this be because I'm using eclipse+Mac OSX?

Comment: Have you run it on a real device?

Comment: yes. gives the same sort of image on my HTC one.